# My server throws 404 on the page that has been edited with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I set my profile link to www.myweb.com/username
but when i goto that link it redirects me to 404.000webhost.com
here is what's in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
```

it works perfectly in my local server, but does not work on the live server. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you post your full htaccess file?

Comment: @RichardCheng - Did you include `RewriteEngine On` at the top?

Comment: Yes i did. The other rules work only that rule dont.